# Python package like helmet(js)?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, npm, helmet.js

I'm constructing an api in python with Flask(python package) and i wanna add some security headers in this api, in nodejs(express) i usually use the [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) package.
Some on know a package like helmet in python?

Comment: [Helmet's "See also" page](https://helmetjs.github.io/see-also/) recommends [Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman).

Comment: tks, it works for me :D